# ksh + delete number from string

Tags: linux, shell-script, perl, ksh

the string IP include some IP address numbers
as the following example

```
echo ${IP[*]}

192.9.200.1 192.9.200.2 192.9.200.3
```

is it possible to remove some IP address number from the list ( using ksh shell ) ?

for example

I want to delete the IP - 192.9.200.2 from the string "IP"

so I will get the following

```
echo ${IP[*]}

192.9.200.1 192.9.200.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IP=(192.9.200.1 192.9.200.2 192.9.200.3)
remove=192.9.200.2
new=()
for ip in "${IP[@]}"; do [[ $ip != $remove ]] && new+=($ip); done
echo "${new[*]}"
```

```
192.9.200.1 192.9.200.3
```

Or

```
for ((i=0; i<${#IP[@]}; i++)); do
    [[ ${IP[i]} == $remove ]] && unset IP[i]
done
echo "${IP[*]}"
```

```
192.9.200.1 192.9.200.3
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but since they are not hashed, you have to iterate over each element:

```
i=0
for item in "${IP[@]}"; do
    if [ "$item" = 192.9.200.2 ]; then
        unset IP["$i"]
        break # Remove this if the item could appear more than once
    fi
    let i++
done
```

Comment: Is the separate i variable used due to a specific `ksh` version? For now I can only check MirBSD Korn Shell, but there `for item in "${!IP[@]}"; do if [ "${IP[item]}" = 192.9.200.2 ]; then unset IP[item]; fi ; done` works.

Comment: @manatwork I'm not totally sure how portable `"${!var[@]}"` is in older ksh variants, so I avoided it.